# How do I group header and details in a RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to do the following in an RDLC Report:

I have a table:

ChequeTmp

> [ChequeNum], [ChequeDate], [ChequeAmount], [Invoice], [InvoiceDate], [InvoiceAmount]

*There can be multiple cheques in the the ChequeTmp table and for each cheque there can be 0 or many stub lines.*

**How do I display this data on an RDLC report?
Note: I have to first display cheque info followed by its stub details and then another cheque followed by its respective stub details**

PS:
I am trying to achieve the following design:
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some examples of data and desired report design. But from what you are saying, my best guess would be to consolidate data into single table and use row grouping to group and format the report. (Hint: Table can have one one datasource)

Comment: @InitK: I have modified my question as per your suggestion.
Can you please suggest a design

Comment: @InitK: FYI, when I try to add the table with Invoice, Invoice Date and Invoice Amount it says me that details member cannot contain inner members (only static inner memebers are allowed).

Comment: By "consolidating the data" I mean "flattening" data set, so every record of it contains all the data from the top-level grouping along with the details from the invoice details part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

1. Place the header data and details data in a single table.
2. Add a Table to RDLC Report and set its data set to that single
   table.
3. Add a group: ADJACENT ABOVE
4. Delete the details row group.
5. Add a row in the adjacent group.
6. Merge cells in the first row and put all your header details here in
   a rectangle.
7. Create another table outside of the first table and assign your
   details to it.
8. Drag and drop that table to the first table adjacent row.

Comment: I can't follow this.

Comment: @m-albert: Do you need more help on this?